# Partial Ready drives in DDN storage

Tags: storage

We have a storage array : DDN SFA7700 with an extension.

The warranty is over and we prepare the new storage to copy the data. But we still need two-three weeks until the new storage will be operational.

Unfortunately, we had a big problem with our conditioner in data center.
Once the problem was resolved, I discovered that about 15 drives in the extension are marked as "Partial Ready" state.
As I understood from documentation, it means that these drives are seen only by one controller (in our case the controller 1).

We restarted the storage twice, but still the same result : the drives are still in partially ready state.

As I understood, the data could be accessible, but if I lose the controller number 1, I could lose all of data.
I have a colleague that had some similar problem in the past with another storage (Dell), but the problem was solved by restarting storage. So it seems that it does not work for us.

So, I'd like to know if somebody had seen this problem before and could give me an advice?

Answer (score 1):

DDN is a very small player in this market so I'd be surprised if someone here has has EXACTLY the same problem but there will be many people here, including myself, that have seen similar problems on similar arrays.

If I read your question correctly you have a working array but some of the disks cannot be seen my one of the two controller - but you're about to start migrating all data from it to a new array. If that is correct and you intend to move the data VERY soon then I'd be inclined to just carry on with the fault and focus on getting off the array as soon as possible rather than pay money to fix an array that won't be in service for long. That said if the data migration is weeks or months away from being complete I may choose to get it fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying.
As I said, we are planning to migrate the data, but we need at least two weeks before **starting** migration. And we need time to migrate the data.

If I understand, it's probably not a good idea to try to fix by ourself (even without speaking that we have not idea how to fix it for the moment).
So the options :
1) search somebody (and search money for somebody) to get it fixed ;
2) launch the storage and hurry the deployment of new storage and migration ;

Option 2 is more reasoned but risky.
Option 1 is expensive and complcated but minimize the risk